# What is the probability that a Chi-square distribution lies within 2 standard deviation of its mean?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Here I have an 8 degrees of freedom Chi-square distribution function $f(x)$

So by definition, $E(X)=8, Var(X)=2*8=16$. (Please guide me if this is wrong. We just started this chapter and there's nothing much going on)

So does that mean we are looking for the probability of X lies between $8 \pm 16 \implies 0<X<24$?

By using R, I was able to approximate the probability being $0.99771$. But that seems wrong since it's pretty much the entire distribution.

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong here.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the variance is $16$, the standard deviation is $4$.

Comment: thanks!! i completely forgot that.

Comment: So $x \in [0,16]$, by using pchisq(16,df=8) - pchisq(0,df=8) = 0.9576199?

Comment: Also, chi-squared is fat on the left of the mean and a long tail. That is why you pretty much eat up most of the density at $\pm 2 \sigma$

Answer (score 2):

16  is the *variance*, your interal is 2x too large. You want $8\pm 8$